# In this example of recursion, how come the second printline prints the second half of the output?

Tags: java, recursion

I understand how calling the recursion method (n-1) prints out 4 3 2 1, and since on the last one, n=0; it breaks out of the loop I think, however, my lack of understanding comes from how the second print line prints 1 2 3 4.

```
static void recursion(int n) {
    if(n>0) {
        System.out.println(n);
        recursion(n-1);
        System.out.println(n);
    }
    
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
recursion(4);
}
```

}

output:
4
3
2
1
1
2
3
4

Comment: put a println in the method as the first line and see

Comment: `t breaks out of the loop I think,` no, there is no loop, it just returns to caller function, with "previous" N value stored in N

Comment: You are not returning any values. it just prints the value assigned to it, so when assigned 4, it prints 4 goes into recursion, ..., comes out of recursion, then prints 4 again. this is because the n value is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
You call recursion(4)
  which prints 4
  then calls recursion(3)
    which prints 3  
    then calls recursion(2)
      which prints 2
      then calls recursion(1)
        which prints 1
        then calls recursion(0)
          which does nothing
          and returns to the previous level
        which prints 1
        and returns to the previous level
      which prints 2
      and returns to the previous level
    which prints 3
    and returns to the previous level
  which prints 4
  and returns to the previous level
and we're done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).